# neat pythonで交差検定の実装について

Tags: python

neat pythonは交差検定が実装されていないのですが、実装コードを教えてください。以前
Scikit-learnで可能とのアドバイスをいただきましたが、Scikit-learnではNEATは実装されていなかったかと思うので、Scikit-learnを用いての実装についてもご教授いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

もうご覧になっていないかもしれませんが，`neat-python`公式ページの`xor2`を以下のように実装して動いているようです．

```
from neat import nn, population
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

class neatXorClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pop = population.Population('xor2_config')

    @staticmethod
    def eval_fitness(genomes):
        for g in genomes:
            net = nn.create_feed_forward_phenotype(g)
            sum_square_error = 0.0
            for inputs, expected in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
                # Serial activation propagates the inputs through the entire network.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                output = net.serial_activate(inputs)
                sum_square_error += (output[0] - expected) ** 2
                # When the output matches expected for all inputs, fitness will reach                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                # its maximum value of 1.0.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                g.fitness = 1 - sum_square_error

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.pop.run(self.eval_fitness, 300)

    def predict(self, X):
        winner = self.pop.statistics.best_genome()
        winner_net = nn.create_feed_forward_phenotype(winner)
        output = []
        for inputs in X:
            output.append(round(winner_net.serial_activate(inputs)[0]))
        return output

#    def score(self, X, y):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#        if len(X) == 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#            return 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#        pred = self.predict(X)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#        return len(list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==x[1],zip(pred,y))))/len(pred)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

if __name__=='__main__':
    xor_inputs = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
    xor_outputs = [0, 1, 1, 0]

    nxc = neatXorClassifier()
    print(cross_val_score(nxc, xor_inputs, y=xor_outputs, cv=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

ご質問は一般に交差検定の実装ですか，それともNeat特有の問題ですか?
scikit-learnでK分割の交差検定をするだけなら

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
import numpy
X = numpy.array([[1,2],[0,4],[4,5],[2,3]]) # feature
y = numpy.array([0.9,-0.1,1.2,15.3])       # answer
kf = cross_validation.KFold(len(X), n_folds=2) # 2-validation
for train_index, test_index in kf:
     X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
     y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

これでできるはずです．ループの中で学習データ(x_train,y_train)とテストデータ(x_test,y_test)に分割されるので．学習データで学習して，テストデータでスコアを測ればよいです．
個人的な疑問ですが，Neatで評価するスコアは何ですか? 少しNeat Pythonのページを見たかんじではテストデータから予測する方法がわからないからです.

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。説明不足で失礼いたしました。やろうとしていることは、"Neat Python"(http://neat-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)をscikit learn準拠の学習にすることで、scikit learnのK-fold Cross Validationを使えるようにしたい。ということなのですが、sklearn.base.BaseEstimatorでできそうなのですが、手をこまねいているという状態です。また、NEATで評価するのは、入力ー＞出力の誤差で、genome.pyに記述されています。具体的には、xor2.pyのExampleでは、Fitness Functionは、error += (output[0] - expected) ** 2です。

Comment: こちらにあるように自前の推定器を定義するということですね．(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator)
このページにあるようにsklearn.base.BaseEstimatorを継承したclassを定義し，cross_validationを行うためには学習するメソッドfitとスコアを計算するscoreメソッドを定義すればよいと思います．xor2.pyの例だとfitに相当する学習部分は
`pop = population.Population('xor2_config')
pop.run(eval_fitness, 300)`
の部分で，予測をしてるのが
`output = winner_net.serial_activate(inputs)`
でこの`output`と正解を比較しスコアを計算したいということですね．

Comment: 貴重なアドバイズありがとうございます。自分でやってみたのですが、どうもうまくいかないようです。
class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self,**xor2_config):
        self.xor2_config('xor2_config')
        self.pop.epoch=pop.epoch

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.pop=population.Population('xor2_config')
        self.pop.epoch(eval_fitness, 100)
        return self

    def predict(self, x):
        output=self.winner_net.serial_activate(inputs)
        return output
というように組んでみたのですが、どこが問題なのですしょうか？どう直せばいいか分からないので、何卒、ご教授いただけますと非常に助かります。

Comment: 貴重なアドバイズありがとうございます。自分でやってみたのですが、どうもうまくいかないようです。
 class MyEstimator(BaseEstimator): <br/>
　def __init__(self,**xor2_config): 、<br/>
　self.xor2_config('xor2_config') 、<br/>
　self.pop.epoch=pop.epoch def fit(self, x, y):、<br/>
 self.pop=population.Population('xor2_config')、<br/>
 self.pop.epoch(eval_fitness, 100) 、<br/>
return self def predict(self, x): <br/>
output=self.winner_net.serial_activate(inputs) 、<br/>
return output 、<br/>
というように組んでみたのですが、どこが問題なのですしょうか？どう直せばいいか分からないので、何卒、ご教授いただけますと非常に助かります 。（みずらいので、改行しました）

Comment: どのような問題(エラーメッセージ)ですか? あと示されたクラスだと`score`メソッドが必要だと思います．